# Unable to SSH to a local system; error (publickey, password), SSH key regeneration

Tags: networking, ssh, authentication, openssh

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 desktop and unable to SSH into it, getting the error(publickey, password).

Here are the logs :

```
ssh -vvv titan@192.168.0.122 

OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.0.122 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.122 [192.168.0.122] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/focal/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/focal/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/focal/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/focal/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/focal/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/focal/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/focal/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/focal/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/focal/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/focal/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/focal/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/focal/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/focal/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/focal/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.0.122:22 as 'titan'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/focal/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/focal/.ssh/known_hosts:25
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.0.122
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:DL9fd8mBHQHYpOoW+JPNBHV59zdnLcZ/eSgslpp2MyQ
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/focal/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/focal/.ssh/known_hosts:25
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.0.122
debug1: Host '192.168.0.122' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/focal/.ssh/known_hosts:25
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/focal/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:NuGqpwc/RSaS5YDdylCqrdnkobzJVVnKtccq6Ia+omM agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/focal/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/focal/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/focal/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/focal/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/focal/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/focal/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/focal/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:NuGqpwc/RSaS5YDdylCqrdnkobzJVVnKtccq6Ia+omM agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/focal/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/focal/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/focal/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/focal/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/focal/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/focal/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/focal/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/focal/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/focal/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/focal/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/focal/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /home/focal/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
titan@192.168.0.122's password: 
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Comment: Not at all, I'm using the same password to login into that very system, but can't login using SSH

Comment: I logged into my server with `vvv` options using publickey authentication. Our debugs look the same until the line `receive packet: type 51`. I got `type 52` and the next line says `Authentication succeeded (publickey)`. I  would say your keys are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config` in terminal.

Look for `PasswordAuth...` And set it to "`yes`". The line should look like:

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Save the file and exit.

Then type into the terminal:

```
sudo systemctl reload sshd.service
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved the issue, didn't know this was the problem, could you tell how could this have happened? It was  working fine 3-4 hours ago, and suddenly started to cause problem in SSH.